# How to add page specific script tag in tymeleaf layout decorator?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Lets say, I have following layout page tmeplate.html

```
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
...
<body>
   ...
   <section layout:fragment="custom-content">
     DEFAULT CONTENT GOES HERE
   </section>
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

and my index.html page is like following

```
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
   layout:decorator="template">
...
<body>
  ...
  <section layout:fragment="custom-content">
      PAGE SPECIFIC CONTENT GOES HERE
  </section>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

So, how do I add index.html page specific ***script*** tag immediate before the ending ***body*** tag?